# VBA SQL Intersect replacement for datasets from the same table. (MS Access)

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, intersect

I believe 'Intersect' is the solution to my problem, but implementing it in VBA is throwing me..

I have two tables:

1. Items, for our purposes a single column of [ItemNumber]
2. ItemProperties, 2 columns [ItemNumber],[ItemProperty]

Each item as at least (no less then) 2 properties [ItemProperty] and as many as 700 properties.

For each Item in the Items table, I want to compare it with every other Item in the Item Table and see if they have any Properties in common.

My thought was to use:

Reading through Items with two loops. the first loop to select the current item [FristItem], the second to select what item I am comparing to it [SecondItem]

```
Select ItemProperty from ItemProperties where ItemNumber = FirstItem
Intersect
Select ItemProperty from ItemProperties where ItemNumber = SecondItem
```

That,I believe will give me the properties in common between FirstItem and SecondItem.

But MS Access VBA does not implement Intersect.
The discussions I have seen talk about how to use INNER JOIN to accomplish the same thing, but always uses 2 different Tables as the sources..  When I write it as from a single table, I seem to get ambiguous identifies on the ON part (same identifier on both sides..)

I am a relative beginner at SQL and am sure the answer is simple and obvious, but I am just missing it today.
In the end I need to do something based on the number of common properties each pair has, but I think I have that part worked out.. Just need help with the Intersect / INNER JOIN..

Thank you anyone who can point me in the right direction

dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a `GROUP BY` instead. Use `HAVING` to make sure both FirstItem and SecondItem are there.

```
Select ItemProperty
from ItemProperties
where ItemNumber in (FirstItem, SecondItem)
having max(ItemNumber) <> min(ItemNumber)
```

*self join* alternative:

```
select distinct i1.ItemProperty
from ItemProperties i1
join ItemProperties i2
  on i1.ItemProperty = i2.ItemProperty
where i1.ItemNumber = FirstItem
  and i2.ItemNumber = SecondItem
```

Comment: it says I am missing an operator in the 'count' expression

Comment: It does? I've never used MS Access. Check back in a minute or two, and I'll come up with something else.

Comment: OK i see how this works, and I think it is what I want..  if I take off the 'having count' clause, it returns the total set of records that match the two item keys.  so all of set a and all of set b, then the having clause should only report those where i have duplicates (indicating 1 from each set, or a match)

Comment: So it makes sense, but I keep getting an error on the 'count' clause..  'missing operator' if i run it from an access query or from VBA.  >> Having Count(Distinct Itemproperties.property) > 1; << (I want to see if the properties duplicate, not the item numbers..)

Comment: Can you try `having max(ItemNumber) <> min(ItemNumber)`?

Comment: MSAccess does not have `COUNT(DISTINCT ...`

Comment: @tinazmu, thank you for the information. But can you do `having max(ItemNumber) <> min(ItemNumber)`?

Comment: Yes, @jarih, you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use: this SQL (or similar):

```
select IPA.ItemName, IPA.ItemProperty, IPB.ItemName as CommonWithThisItem
from   ItemProperties as IPA
           inner join
           ItemProperties as IPB
           on IPA.ItemName>IPB.ItemName
                 and IPA.ItemProperty=IPB.ItemProperty
```

The greater than criteria used forces only one of the two combinations to be returned (i.e. say, the item names having a comoon property are ItemA and ItemB; normally both ItemA, ItemB, and ItemB, ItemA would be valid returns for your query). If this is not what you want, change the `>` criteria to `<>`